# Cassandra 2.1 : User Defined Types - Achilles - Java Mapping

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-2.1

How do we map `User Defined Types` in Java using `Achilles` Java Library in Cassandra 2.1? Particularly, an implementation/example to [this link](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql-in-2-1) would be helpful.

```
 CREATE TYPE address (
      street text,
      city text,
      zip int
  );

  CREATE TABLE user_profiles (
      login text PRIMARY KEY,
      first_name text,
      last_name text,
      email text,
      addresses map<text, address>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

To map User Defined Type in Java using Achilles , you can use @UDT annotation. In your case , Address Bean will look like this :

@UDT(name="address",keyspace = "your_keyspcae_name")
class Address{

@Column("street")
private String street;

@Column("city")
private String city;

@Column("zip")
private int zip;

//getter and setter methods

.
.
.
.
}

and your main table mapping will look like :

@Table(table="user_profile",keyspace="your_keyspace_name")
class UserProfiles{

.
.
.
.

@Column("addresses")
private Map addresses;

.
.
.
.

}

Hope this will help you.